# Открытие элементов recycleview и отображение данных в соответствии с id

Tags: java, android-studio, recyclerview, kotlin, recyclerview.adapter

Необходимо получить список пользователей, отобразить в RecyclerView поля `name`, `age`, `country`, `city` на каждого пользователя. Всё отображается. Возникли трудности, как открыть определённого пользователя? На каждого пользователя есть уникальные поля `id` и `about`. При нажатии на кнопку около определённого пользователя, открывать новую активити с полем `about` пользователя.

```
{
    "users": [{
        "id": "00001",
        "name": "Ben",
        "age": 24,
        "url": "https://facebook.com/niuf23r",
        "type": "Student",
        "country": "Russion Federation",
        "city": "Moscow",
        "about": "I'd like tell about Kotlin.",
        "status": "Kotlin developer"
    }, {
        "id": "00002",
        "name": "Alex",
        "age": 28,
        "url": "https://facebook.com/mi45ert4",
        "type": "Student",
        "country": "Russion Federation",
        "city": "St.Peterburgs",
        "about": "I'd like tell about Java.",
        "status": "Java developer"
    }, {
        "id": "00003",
        "name": "Mona",
        "age": 21,
        "url": "https://facebook.com/mid5efw4",
        "type": "Student",
        "country": "Russion Federation",
        "city": "St.Peterburgs",
        "about": "I'd like tell about C++.",
        "status": "C++ developer"
    }, {
        "id": "00004",
        "name": "Nikola",
        "age": 24,
        "url": "https://facebook.com/rb4fw4",
        "type": "Student",
        "country": "Russion Federation",
        "city": "St.Peterburgs",
        "about": "I'd like tell about PHP.",
        "status": "PHP developer"
    }, {
        "id": "00005",
        "name": "Lio",
        "age": 24,
        "url": "https://facebook.com/bwwert4",
        "type": "Student",
        "country": "Russion Federation",
        "city": "St.Peterburgs",
        "about": "I'd like tell about Python.",
        "status": "Python developer"
    }]
}
```

*CustomAdapter.kt*

```
class CustomAdapter(private val context: Context, private val userList: ArrayList<Users>)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    companion object {
        const val lNAME = "Имя: "
        const val lSTATUS = "Статус: "
        const val lAGE = "Возраст: "
        const val lCITY = "Город: "
    }

    private var listOfEstablishments = userList
    fun setListUsers(list: List<Users>) {
        userList.addAll(list)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: ViewHolder?, position: Int) {
        p0 ?: return
        val user: Users = userList[position]
        p0.tvName.text = lNAME + user.name
        p0.tvStatus.text = lSTATUS + user.status
        p0.tvAge.text = lAGE + user.age.toString()
        p0.tvCity.text = lCITY + user.city
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup?, p1: Int): ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(p0?.context).inflate(R.layout.list_layout, p0, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = userList.size

    fun getItemByPosition(pos: Int): Users = listOfEstablishments[pos]

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var infoBtnClickListener: ((view: View?, position: Int, item: Long) -> Unit)? = null

        val tvName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName) as TextView
        val tvStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvStatus) as TextView
        val tvAge = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAge) as TextView
        val tvCity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCity) as TextView
        val btnAbout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnAbout) as Button

        init { }
    }
}
```

*MainActivity.kt*

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val compositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false)
        val users = ArrayList<Users>()
        val adapter = CustomAdapter(this, users)

        val repository = SearchRepositoryProvider.provideSearchRepository()

        compositeDisposable.add(
                repository.searchUsers()
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .subscribe({ result ->
                            adapter.setListUsers(result.users)
                        }, { error ->
                            error.printStackTrace()
                        })
        )

        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        compositeDisposable.clear()
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам потребуется в адаптере описать интерфейс, а в классе вашей `Activity` реализовать этот интерфейс

---

В вашем классе адаптера опишите интерфейс, допустим такой:

```
interface OnItemClickListener {
   fun onItemClick(user: Users)
}
```

И объявите его в классе адаптера:

```
private var _onItemClickListener: OnItemClickListener? = null
```

Определите в адаптере метод установки слушателя:

```
fun setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener: OnItemClickListener) {
    _onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener
}
```

На кнопку `btnAbout` в `onBindViewHolder` повесьте обработчик нажатий. При нажатии на кнопку будет вызываться метод вашего интерфейса:

```
btnAbout.setOnClickListener { _onItemClickListener?.onItemClick(user) }
```

---

Перейдём к `MainActivity`. Тут вам потребуется просто реализовать этот интерфейс:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CustomAdapter.OnItemClickListener
```

А в `onCreate` при объявлении адаптера указать вашу `MainActivity` как реализующую этот интерфейс:

```
val adapter = CustomAdapter(this, users)
adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this@MainActivity)
```

Теперь переопределяем все методы интерфейса, в данном случае он один. В вашем случае, делаем в нём старт активити, где будет подробная информация о пользователе, объект `Users` можно передавать через `Intent`, если он конечно `Parcelable`:

```
override fun onItemClick(user: Users) {
   Toast.makeText(this, "Выбран " + user.name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
   // Делаем, что хотим
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за очень подробное объяснение. Я понял как это работает. Сделал по вашему методу.