# Обработка нажатия на item в RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite, recyclerview

У меня есть список recyclerview, который выводит названия блюд из БД SQLite. Для него я создал обработчик событий RecyclerItemClickListener, но пока он выводит только тост. Что сделать, что бы при нажатии на элемент открывалось второе активити с подробной информацией о рецепте(Ингридиенты, рецепт).

Comment: Надеюсь тебе поможет ответ на мой вопрос.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/828527/265057

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Напишите в адаптере для `ViewHolder'a` метод `onClick` и в нем:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (YourActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.put("dishId", list.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId());
и т.д.
startActivity(intent);
```

Во втором Активити найдите по Id ваше блюдо. `getIntent().getInt("dishId");`

Естественно, надо все делать через паттерн MVC (почитайте, если не знаете).

Или можете делать все "ручками", складывать (`put`) в `intent` все параметры по одному и так же их доставать